# Moho, run script and get ScriptInterface instance

Tags: lua

I need to run Moho lua script which created new document, import some files etc., by command line.
The problem is: to call this function requered ScriptInterface instance. It may called by mouse clicking, by menu selection in Moho ui (hand made calling) and sending ScriptingInterface instance as function parameter, like script:Run(moho). If I trying to call this function from commandline this instance not set as parameter.
So the question is - can I take ScriptInterface instance from some global vars or from somewhere else ??

Answer (score 0):

You can prepare a special .moho file, which includes a layer with embed lua script. If you run command line opening Moho with this special file in it, it will execute the layer script (because it is executed on every new frame enter)  and script will receive ScriptInterface instance as moho argument given to its LayerScript function.